# my javascript checkbox doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

http://codepen.io/PaxBlueRibbon/pen/wWJWXj

I'm trying to teach myself Javascript, but this fahrenheit/celsius switch doesn't do anything.  I set up my switch like this:

```
$(document).ready(function getPosition() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    var unit = "Fahrenheit";
  } else {
    var unit = "Celsius";
  }
```

and set conditionals in the JS like this

```
      var tempKelvin = json.main.temp;
      var tempFahrenheit = tempKelvin * 1.8 - 459.67;
      var tempCelsius = tempKelvin - 273.15;
      if (unit == "Fahrenheit") {
        $(".temp").html(Math.round(tempFahrenheit) + " Degrees " + unit);
      }
      if (unit == "Celsius") {
$(".temp").html(Math.round(tempCelsius) + " Degrees " + unit);
      }
```

The fahrenheit works, and if I change the variable to something else it stops working, but I can't get it to show Celsius.

Comment: You are only setting the value of `unit` once. You will need to change it when your `myonoffswitch` is changed.

Comment: is your switch a checkbox or radio button? I think you might need to check the status of your switch dynamically by using an event handler.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXOVGa  if you look at the console, you will note that the unit is being updated, however not being detected in the json function. I put a log in the json function to show the current unit and it always seemed to show Fahrenheit, regardless of change???

Comment: i think you may have to pass it into the json function

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery.

```
// you should add event listener.
$('#myonoffswitch').change(function(){
    // and change "unit" every time checkbox is changed
    unit = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius';
    // change html here
});
```

And you can call this event on page load

```
$('#myonoffswitch').change();
```

Comment: i'm trying to figure out where in my code to place these so they run at the proper time

Comment: I would suggest you to rearrange your code a bit. First define your _global_ variables, like `var unit, location;` etc at the top and change each of them accordingly ( eq. checkbox changed, JSON loaded, etc.).  Divide each action into separate functions. (eq. getLocation(), drawHTML(), etc). Call them whenever they are needed (eq. Page Loaded, checkbox changed, time intervar, etc) and let them use _global_ variables defined earlier.

Comment: $(document).ready() specifies that everything inside it will be executed when the page loads. Always put event bindings inside it to assure that you are binding to an element that has been created.